# Create alphabetical letter numbering for list in erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, html-lists, erb

I want to put a letter next to an answer in alphabetical order.

Like this:

```
a. answer one
b. answer two
c. answer three
```

and so on...

This is what I was trying but I can't figure out how to only put the letter if there is an answer.

```
<% @a = ("a".."z").to_a %>
<% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
  <tr>
    <% if answer %>
    <% @a.each do |letter| %>
      <td><% letter %></td>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <td><%= answer.option %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What templating engine is that? This isn't pure Ruby.

Comment: What if you have more than 26 answers?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Haha, thanks for your concern. Then I will poop on someone's desk. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`each_with_index`](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Enumerable/each_with_index), which also passes the index of the current object in the array to the block. This means that the first answer will have `i == 0`, the second `i == 1`, etc.

`@a` is also an array, with the letters ordered in it, so at position `0` there is the letter `"a"`, `1` - `"b"`, etc.

Now all you have to do is print the letter in position `i` before the answer in position `i`:

```
<% @a = ("a".."z").to_a %>
<% question.answers.each_with_index do |answer, i| %>
  <tr>
    <% if answer %>
      <td><%= @a[i] %></td>
    <% end %>
  <td><%= answer.option %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Btw, either the `if` is redundant, or you have to put `answer.option` in it - otherwise you will try to call `.option` on `nil`...

```
<% @a = ("a".."z").to_a %>
<% question.answers.each_with_index do |answer, i| %>
  <tr>
    <% if answer %>
      <td><%= @a[i] %></td>

      <td><%= answer.option %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: +1 Clean, I will have to learn that each_with_index, very nice

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using the built-in [html listing functionality](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.3.1):

```
<ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

will appear as:

```
a. Coffee
b. Tea
c. Milk
```